# SharePoint 2019 - how to not preview html code in browser and preview html file as a page

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, html, 2019

I am unable to view HTML files uploaded in SharePoint 2019 library. When I click on the files in Chrome, it downloads it. In Edge, when I click on it, it opens html code in preview code editor in the browser.

I want to see a preview page of the html file in the browser when I click on it (just like I can see a Word doc).

I can see the HTML file properly in preview mode in SharePoint 2013.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: you can use below format to preview your page in new tab
http://siteUrl/<libraryname>/file.html

Comment: Gaurav, the file downloads when i format the column and preview the page.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I could reproduce your issue in SharePoint server 2019 modern UI.

As a workaround, "Return to classic SharePoint" will solve the issue.

Comment: It downloads in classic view also. I cannot use classic view anyways. Users need to use modern UI.

Comment: Please go to SharePoint CA>Manage web applications>select the web application and click General settings>Check if the "Browser File Handling" property is set to Permissive.Currently this is by design in modern view and we could not change it.